# How to check what field of the array are not null

Tags: php

My mssql query returns an array of a row in my table, but in that row there are like 5 cells that are null. How can I remove these NULLs from the array so I can if-check the array for a certain field that is set.

My english is pretty bad so the explanation could be pretty hard to understand.

```
ID Name ID1  ID2 ID3
1  Test NULL 1   NULL
```

Is there a function to remove the cells ID1 and ID3

Comment: use assoc fetching and then isset() isset($row['ID3']) will return false

Comment: use array_filter() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function to remove the empty field as

```
$arr1 = array(5, '', 6, '', '', 7);
print_r(array_filter($arr1));
```

Output

```
Array ( [0] => 5 [2] => 6 [5] => 7 )
```